# Asynchronously return _id of inserted post into Mongo collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

There is data inserted into Videos Collection, but future.return always returns only empty object. How to return post _id back to client?

```js
// load future from fibers
var Future = Meteor.npmRequire("fibers/future");
// load fibers
var Fiber = Meteor.npmRequire("fibers");
// load youtubedl
var youtubedl = Meteor.npmRequire('youtube-dl');

Meteor.methods({
  'command' : function(line) {
    // this method call won't return immediately, it will wait for the
    // asynchronous code to finish, so we call unblock to allow this client
    this.unblock();
    var future = new Future();
 youtubedl.getInfo(line, function(err, stdout, stderr, videoId) {
  if(stdout)
    Fiber(function() {
         var videoId = Videos.insert({videoObject: stdout ? stdout : stderr});
         console.log(videoId);
         return videoId; 
          }).run();
  future.return({_id: videoId})
 });
 return future.wait();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `meteorhacks:npm` it also comes with Async tools it's easier to use. https://github.com/meteorhacks/npm#async-utilities

and here is an example:

```
// load future from fibers
var Future = Meteor.npmRequire("fibers/future");
// load fibers
var Fiber = Meteor.npmRequire("fibers");
// load youtubedl
var youtubedl = Meteor.npmRequire('youtube-dl');

Meteor.methods({
  'command' : function(line) {
    // this method call won't return immediately, it will wait for the
    // asynchronous code to finish, so we call unblock to allow this client
    this.unblock();

    var videoId = Async.runSync(function (done) {
        youtubedl.getInfo(url, options, function (err, info) {
            if (err) throw new Error(err);

            var videoData = {
                id: info.id,
                title: info.title,
                url: info.url //and so on...
            };

            // var videoId = Videos.insert(videoData);
            // for demo purposes we return randomIdHere
            var videoId = "randomIdHere"
            done(null, videoId); // when done execute this callback with any data
        });
    });

    return videoId;

  }
});
```

Comment: It always gets an error bc you need to run it in Fibers

Comment: @mhlavacka you don't have to user fibers, `Async.runSync()` will run it sync the example code is a working code which will return the `videoId` to the client